# Unix command for Date conversion from timestamp to standard dateformat?

Tags: java, unix

I need to convert date from timestamp(eg: 1362553920) format to standard date format (DD:MM:YYYY HH:MM:SS).

Is there any unix commands available for this?.

If it is not possible in unix, how can I do it in java ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
date -d @1362553920
Wed Mar  6 08:12:00 CET 2013
```

This is unix command, where `@xxxxxxxxxx` is your input

You could also add some format parameters for "cut" the output only to certain values like time, or week day and so on

Type `man date` into terminal for more information

Answer (score 2):

In Java:

```
java.util.Date dt = new java.util.Date(1362553920L * 1000L);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(sdf.format(dt));
```

but I'm sure there must be some Unix tool to achieve this as well ;)

Comment: Should be `new java.util.Date(1362553920L * 1000L)` because in Java timestamp is in milliseconds, while in Unix it is in seconds.

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov: ah, thanks. I thought Unix was using milliseconds as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
date -r 1362553920 +'%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'
```

Output for me is

```
06.03.2013 11:12:00
```

Oh, this is FreeBSD-specific.  Looks like `date` command does not have standard switch for this so you need to check manual page for `date` on your system to know how to specify timestamp to it.